# Fixed Space Bar Button Item places buttons outside of screen

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I want to implement a toolbar in my iOS app, which displays the App's logo in the center of the toolbar and shows a `+` button on the right side.

So, I placed a Toolbar element on the view, then two bar button items (logo and add symbol) and placed two flexible space bar button items between them.

It now looks like this:

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05334.png)

While this looks exactly like the desired behavior, it does not look like this in the simulator:

[Simulator Portrait Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL7qM.png)

When testing the app with the iPhone 6s, the logo part is a little bit more to the left, but still not in the center. I am obviously doing something wrong, because I thought the point of "flexible space bar button items" is to dynamically adapt to different resolutions. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `UINavigationBar` instead of a `UIToolbar`.

`UINavigationBar` is for the top of the screen since it has a shadow on its bottom edge. It also supports having a title/titleView that is centred.

`UIToolbar` is for the bottom of the screen since it has a shadow on its top edge. It does not have properties for adding a title so you would have to do it manually. Also, flexible space lays out the elements so each flexible width item has the same width.